# Compilation of Release configuration fails (ILT0005)

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I've updated Visual Studio 2015 to Update 2 recently. Since then, I'm not able to compile my already published app anymore. Even a new blank UWP project does not compile. I get the following error message:

ILT0005: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\Tools\nutc_driver.exe @"C:\Users\locked\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App1\App1\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\App1.rsp"" Exitcode -1073740791

I completely uninstalled all Visual Studio relevant components and reinstalled them, which didn't solve the problem. Unfortunately, I'm not able to update my app at the moment.

I'm running Windows 10 Build 10586.218

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug in .NET Native compiler, affecting German localization only (based on our current knowledge). We are looking into solutions (a fix with reasonable shipping vehicle, or better workaround). Stay tuned.

[Update] The fix shipped on 6th May as "Universal Windows App Development Tools - Tools (1.3.2)". Go to Control Panel - Programs - Programs and Features - Visual Studio ... - Modify, check Tools (1.3.2), then click Update. All languages now work (German, French, Italian, etc.).

-Karel Zikmund
(.NET Native team)

Comment: Thanks for the details! Actually, it affects also French localization (my Visual Studio has been installed in this language)

Comment: @Karel Zikmund please add Italian to the bugged ones.

Comment: @Karel Zikmund: is this bug completelly fixed? I get the same exception on an app, whereas it worked fine during monthes... My Windows is in french, but I have VS in english, and english is the only language I have in "International Settings".

Comment: It is possible the bug was reintroduced again by mistake.I would recommend to contact .NET Native support alias (I don't work directly on .NET Native anymore).

Answer (score 0):

i had exactly this issue on french platform and found this solution : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9d590372-d82c-4075-9ea9-504a22c9502f/cant-compile-in-net-native-ilt005-error?forum=wpdevelop

compilation is ok after moved all ressources files nutcui.dll