# Windows Runtime metadata is invalid in SDK - ITIL00005

Tags: xamarin, compiler-errors, xamarin.forms, uwp

I can compile my `UWP` app built with Xamarin in `Debug`-mode, but when I try to compile it using `Release->ARM` mode, these errors occurs

```
ILT0005: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\ARM\ilc\tools\Gatekeeper.exe @"C:\Users\Source\app\project.UWP\obj\ARM\Release\ilc\intermediate\gkargs.rsp"' returned exit code 1     
Error: Windows Runtime metadata is invalid in Windows SDK, follow the steps in http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733341 to repair your installation.
```

I tried to reinstall using the `Windows Software Development Kit - Windows 10.0.10586.212` and `Windows Software Development Kit - Windows 10.0.26624`.

Shall I have both `Development Kits`? 
Or which one do I have to remove?

Or what can cause the problem? 
And how shall I fix it?

I am running `Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 2` and `Windows 10 Pro version 1511`.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666014/compilation-of-release-configuration-fails-ilt0005), but without success, as I am running Visual Studio in English.

My target and min. version is set to `Windows 10 (10.0; Build 10240)`

Comment: i am got this type of error please help me,.

Comment: I removed all Windows SDK's and let Visual Studio download the one it needed, which worked.

Comment: I removed all Windows SDK's and let Visual Studio download the one it needed, as Lasse Madsen did, but It ditn't worked for me, so I download the standalone version, wich worked  (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove all Windows SDK's, you can let Visual Studio download them, which worked for me. 
Otherwise you can download the [Windows SDK's](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and install it.